# Partial trace and SWAP in the basis of subsystems

Tags: quantum-gate, linear-algebra

I'm trying to derive equation $(1)$ on p.2 in [Lloyd *et al*, 2013](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0401) which reads

$$
\text{Tr}_A\left[\exp(-i\theta S_{AB}) (\rho_A \otimes \sigma_B) \exp(i\theta S_{AB}) \right] = (\cos^2 \theta) \sigma_B + (\sin^2 \theta) \rho_B - i \sin \theta [\rho_B, \sigma_B]
$$

where $S_{AB}$ is a swap operator for the two systems. My approach so far is to write the operator as
$$
\exp(i\theta S_{AB}) = \begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\theta} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \theta & i \sin\theta & 0 \\
0 & i \sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i\theta}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{matrix}
\leftarrow\rho_A \otimes \rho_B \\ \leftarrow\rho_A \otimes \sigma_B\\ \leftarrow\sigma_A \otimes \rho_B \\ \leftarrow\sigma_A\otimes \sigma_B
\end{matrix}
$$

where the labels describe how each input is affected by this operation if the possible state configurations are represented as a column vector, e.g. $\rho\otimes \sigma \sim \hat{e}_1$ would become $\cos\theta (\rho\otimes \sigma) + \sin \theta (\sigma \otimes \rho) \sim \cos\theta \hat{e}_1 + \sin \theta \hat{e}_2$.

However, I haven't been able to carry out the calculation since I'm unsure how to apply the operator or partial trace on $(\rho\otimes \sigma)$ when I set up operators like this. Is there anything pathological about this representation of a SWAP, and if so what is the right approach to deriving the above equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ and any operator $T$ such that $T^2=I$ we have

$$
\exp(i\theta T) = I\cos\theta + i T\sin\theta
$$

(c.f. exercise 4.2 on p.175 in Nielsen & Chuang). Therefore,

$$
\exp(i\theta S_{AB}) = I \cos\theta + i S_{AB} \sin\theta
$$

and we have

$$
\exp(-i\theta S_{AB}) (\rho_A \otimes \sigma_B) \exp(i\theta S_{AB}) = \\
\rho_A\otimes\sigma_B \cos^2\theta - i S_{AB} \rho_A\otimes\sigma_B \cos\theta\sin\theta + \\
+ i \rho_A\otimes\sigma_B S_{AB} \cos\theta\sin\theta  + \sigma_A\otimes\rho_B \sin^2\theta.\tag1
$$

By definition

$$
\mathrm{tr}_A(\rho_A\otimes\sigma_B) = \sigma_B \\
\mathrm{tr}_A(\sigma_A\otimes\rho_B) = \rho_B.\tag2
$$

The partial trace of $S_{AB}\rho_A\otimes\sigma_B$ is represented by the tensor network

[image: tensor network for partial trace with swap]

which shows that

$$
\mathrm{tr}_A(S_{AB}\rho_A\otimes\sigma_B) = \rho_B\sigma_B.\tag{3a}
$$

Similarly,

$$
\mathrm{tr}_A(\rho_A\otimes\sigma_BS_{AB}) = \sigma_B\rho_B.\tag{3b}
$$

Finally, tracing over $A$ in $(1)$ and substituting $(2)$, $(3a)$ and $(3b)$, we get

$$
\mathrm{tr}_A\left[\exp(-i\theta S_{AB}) (\rho_A \otimes \sigma_B) \exp(i\theta S_{AB})\right] = \\
\sigma_B\cos^2\theta + \rho_B\sin^2\theta - i\rho_B\sigma_B\cos\theta\sin\theta + i\sigma_B\rho_B\cos\theta\sin\theta = \\
\sigma_B\cos^2\theta + \rho_B\sin^2\theta - i[\rho_B, \sigma_B]\cos\theta\sin\theta.\tag4
$$

---

This result differs from the paper. I think the formula in the paper contains a mistake. Set $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. In this case

$$
\exp\left(-\frac{i\pi S_{AB}}{2}\right) (\rho_A \otimes \sigma_B) \exp\left(\frac{i\pi S_{AB}}{2}\right) = S_{AB} (\rho_A \otimes \sigma_B) S_{AB} = \sigma_A \otimes \rho_B
$$

and the partial trace over $A$ yields $\rho_B$. This special case agrees with $(4)$ and disagrees with the formula in the paper since the latter preserves the term with the commutator when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Using the fact $ e^{i\theta S} = \text{cos}(\theta) \cdot I + i \cdot \text{sin}(\theta) \cdot S $, we calculate

\begin{align*}
e^{-i\theta S} (\rho \otimes \sigma) e^{i\theta S}
& =  
(\text{cos}(\theta) \cdot I - i \cdot \text{sin}(\theta) \cdot S) 
\big(\rho \otimes \sigma \big) 
(\text{cos}(\theta) \cdot I + i \cdot \text{sin}(\theta) \cdot S)  \\
& = \text{cos}^2(\theta) (\rho \otimes \sigma) 
+ \text{sin}^2(\theta) (\sigma \otimes \rho)
- i \text{sin}(\theta) \text{cos}(\theta) \cdot \big( S(\rho \otimes \sigma) - (\rho \otimes \sigma)S \big)
\end{align*}

Now we need only to calculate $ \text{Tr}_A S(\rho \otimes \sigma) $.

Let $ \rho = \sum_i p_i |x_i \rangle \langle x_i| $ and $ \sigma = \sum_i q_i |y_i \rangle \langle y_i| $.

\begin{align*}
\text{Tr}_A S(\rho \otimes \sigma) 
&= \sum_{i,j} p_i q_j \text{Tr}_A [S \big(|x_i y_j \rangle \langle x_i y_j| \big)]
\\ 
&= \sum_{i,j} p_i q_j \text{Tr}_A [\big(|y_j x_i \rangle \langle x_i y_j| \big)]\\
&= \sum_{i,j} p_i q_j \langle x_i | y_j \rangle \cdot|x_i \rangle \langle y_j| = \rho\sigma
\end{align*}
A similar calculation shows that $\text{Tr}_A (\rho \otimes \sigma)S = \sigma \rho$.

Finally:
$$
\text{Tr}_A e^{-i\theta S} (\rho \otimes \sigma) e^{i\theta S} = 
\text{cos}^2(\theta) \sigma
+ \text{sin}^2(\theta) \rho
- i \frac{\text{sin}(2\theta)}{2} \cdot [\rho, \sigma]
$$